# do users need to be asked every time for permission for Google Analytics on iOs?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics for an iPad app. I currently have the following code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary     *)launchOptions
{
 ...



UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Google Analytics" message:@"With your permission usage information will be collected to improve the application." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Opt Out" otherButtonTitles:@"Opt In", nil];
[av show];

return YES;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
        [[GAI sharedInstance] setOptOut:YES];
        break;
    case 1:
        [[GAI sharedInstance] setOptOut:NO];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Currently, it asks the user to opt in/out every time they open the application. Is this needed or can I have the application ask them only once? If I can only ask them once...how can I do that in my code?

To ask on the first time I can use

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if(![defaults boolForKey:@"firstLaunch"]) {
    //this key has never been set - this is the first launch
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"firstLaunch"];

UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Google Analytics" message:@"With   your permission usage information will be collected to improve the application." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Opt Out" otherButtonTitles:@"Opt In", nil];
[av show];
}
```

To update, how would I use this to re ask the user in 7 days if they select opt out.

Comment: Will Apple approve the app without the alert even if I track basic location?

Comment: Yes apple will approve...dont worry go ahead withou alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can ask the user to accept it only once. You can code it the way iOS suggests you to do i.e. Allow the user to turn ON/OFF this feature from Settings app. Ask them the first time; if they allow you pop up that you can turn this feature off from your settings. If they disapprove you can pop up after some days again.

*Note: Providing the user with the alert at least once is must and ethical as per general rule*

**Addition:**

As asked in the comment below you can use UILocalNotification for that. Use the following property

```
@property(nonatomic) NSCalendarUnit repeatInterval
```

> If you assign an calendar unit such as weekly (NSWeekCalendarUnit) or
> yearly (NSYearCalendarUnit), the system reschedules the notification
> for delivery at the specified interval. The default value is 0, which
> means that the system fires the notification once and then discards
> it.

Comment: Thank you. I found that I can use this on first launch..updated above... but if they choose no, how can I have it ask them again in 7 days?

Comment: I submitted as a one time question but this is good to know for future updates. I appreciate you taking the time.